# Don't understand a passage in Showalter (PDEs, sobolev spaces, dual spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Please see this:
[image]
[image]

How does the last equality follow? Why does the duality pairing become an integral over $G$ when test functions are restricted to $L^p$???

Answer (score 2):

So, it looks like $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ indicates the duality pairing between either two $L^2$ (or generally $L^p$) spaces or between $H^1_0$ and its dual $H^{-1}$.

Now, if we have an $H^1_0$ function $f$ and an $H^{-1}$ "function" $g$, it's all well and good to write $\langle f,g \rangle$, but how do you actually calculate it? After all, $g$ could very well be some complicated distribution, and so writing an integral isn't really the right thing to do (often we do this anyway, to be suggestive, but it's just formal).

However, if $g$ is also in $L^2$, we can consider the inclusion map

$$\iota : H^1_0 \hookrightarrow L^2$$

and its adjoint

$$\iota^* : L^2 \hookrightarrow H^{-1}$$

and we will have

$$
\langle \iota f,g \rangle = \langle f,\iota^*g \rangle.
$$

The duality on the right is the $H^1_0,H^{-1}$ bracket we've been trying to evaluate, the one on the left is duality in $L^p$, i.e. it is an integral in the proper sense.

Comment: Thanks for answering. (Let's take $p=2$). I understand your point.. but doesn't this mean we need to use a Hilbert triple situation? In another book (Lions, I asked a question about it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670998/h-1-omega-given-an-inner-product-involving-inverse-laplacian-explanation)), this same result is given, but the author there uses another Hilbert triple $L^2 \subset H^{-1}$ so I am not sure if we can use both at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you're getting at here. We have $L^2 \subset H^{-1}$, and so $H^1_0 = (H^{-1})^* \subset (L^2)^* = L^2$. Now, on one hand, every Hilbert space is isomorphic to its dual (in fact, **all** separable Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic), so you *could* identify $H^1_0$ and $H^{-1}$, but this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: In fact, you see what kind of trouble you get in if you do this: using the notation of your other question, $V = L^2$, $H = H^{-1}$, and $V \subset H$ is (non-surjectively) embedded. Further, $H^* \subset V^*$ is also (non-surjectively) embedded. Now, if you identify $V$ and $V^*$, then you'll have $H^* \subset V^* = V \subset H$, which is fine. But then if you try and identify $H$ and $H^*$, then you get $V \subset H = H^* \subset V^*$, so all the spaces are now equal, which is in conflict with the non-surjectivity of the embeddings.

Comment: The summary of this is that the "natural" identification of Hilbert spaces with their duals is usually not compatible with the inclusions. Thus, you can either identify $V$ with $V^*$, or $H$ with $H^*$, but not both. Making the choice to identify $V$ with $V^*$ winds up being a lot more intuitive and useful, so that's what we go with.